# Get Service Name in HTML Report

Tags: powershell, service

I am developing a simple solution which needs to send an email alert if any service is stopped on my remote server.

Below is the flow:

1. In a notepad file write all services I want to monitor
2. A PowerShell script will read all services from the file and will check its status.
3. If any service is stopped, it will add things to my HTML format and will send an email.

Everything is working fine as per expectation but I am getting `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` instead of the actual service name. I am printing things on the PowerShell console and there I am getting the service name.

Code:

```
$Services = Get-Content D:\Services.txt
foreach ($Service in $Services) {
    Write-Host "Service Name: "$Service
}
```

When I execute this, I am getting service name as expected.

```
if ($Service.Status -eq "Stopped") {
    Write-Host "Service is stopped"
    $dataRow = "<tr><td width='10%'>199.199.50.512</td><td width='10%' >$Service</td><td width='10%' align='center'>Stopped</td></tr>"
    Add-Content $ServiceReport $dataRow;
}
```

Here where `$Service` is written, I am expecing my service name but I am getting `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` in HTML report.

HTML Report:

[image: Wrong HTML Report]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be specific about which property of the object you want to return. You likely want DisplayName, so do this:

```
$dataRow = "<tr><td width='10%'>199.199.50.512</td><td width='10%' >$($Service.displayname)</td><td width='10%' align='center'>Stopped</td></tr>"
```

Note that this is surrounded in a subexpression operator `$()` in order to access the property of the object correctly from within a double quoted string.